# Specifics of a valid Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, measure-theory

In my graduate Math Stats class, my instructor gave me an example of a function that is not a valid random variable (or measurable function):

$\Omega = [0,1)$
$\mathscr{F}=\{\varnothing, [0,1/2), [1/2,1), \Omega\}$

$X: (\Omega , \mathscr{F}, P )\rightarrow  (\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{B})$ and the function is $X(\omega)=\omega$ (the identity function).

The example they gave was:

$X^{-1}((-\infty, 1/3]) = [0,1/3]\notin \mathscr{F}$ and so $X$ is not a random variable on $\mathscr{F}$.

What I understood was that $$\begin{align*}
X^{-1}((-\infty, 1/3]) &= X^{-1}([0, 1/3]) \hspace{1cm} \text{(remove extra information, }(-\infty, 0) \text{ doesn't exist in }\Omega) \\
&= [0,1/3]
\end{align*}$$

which does not map to anything in $\mathscr{F}$ and is therefore not a random variable (or even a measurable function).

The issue comes from thinking about how this applies to another example, as shown:

$\Omega = \{(1,1), (1,2), (2,1),..., (6,5) , (6,6)\}$   (all possible pairs of dice rolls)

$\mathscr{F} = 2^{|\Omega|}$ (the power set of $\Omega$)

$Y:(\Omega , \mathscr{F}, P )\rightarrow  (\Lambda, \mathscr{G})$

$Y(\omega) = i+j$

The problem lies here: $\Lambda = \{2,3,4,...,11,12,13\}$ and $\mathscr{G}$ is the power set of $\Lambda$.

Does $Y^{-1}(13) = \varnothing$  or is $Y$ not a valid random variable?

Thinking in intuitive terms mapping 13 to the null set makes sense because there is a zero probability of rolling a sum of 13 and $\varnothing \in \mathscr{F}$, but looking at $X$ from the previous example, is X not a valid random variable - is that because $[0,1/3]\subset \Omega$ and $[0,1/3]\notin \mathscr{F}$?

Hopefully somebody has an intuitive explanation for me.

Comment: In your last example, indeed $Y^{-1}(13)=\phi$.  $Y$ is a valid random variable, as you are using a sigma algebra as the set of all sets, there is nothing that can go wrong. I would write this as $Y:\Omega\rightarrow \Lambda$, I mislike the notation $Y:(\Omega, F, P)\rightarrow (\Lambda, G)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have trouble understanding why $Y^{-1}(13)=\varnothing$ and $X^{-1}((-\infty,1/3])$ does not.

Comment: I do not understand how you are calling $[0,1/3]$ the empty set.

Comment: Because you used the phrase 'or even a measurable function' - note that a random variable is the same as a measurable function. Its just given a differnt name in probabilty theory, both for historical reasons and because the measure space that is the domain of this function is 'special' (in that a) we typically don't care about its properties, and b) the measure on it is a probability).

Comment: For your above comment: As you said, $X^{-1}(-\infty, 3]$ is just $[0,1/3]$. The non-measurability comes from the fact that the set $[0,1/3]$ is not in $\mathscr{F},$ not because $X$ is not surjective. $Y^{-1}(13)$, on the other hand, is $\varnothing,$ which clearly lies in $2^{[1:6] \times [1:6]}$.

Comment: If your sigma algebra of $\Omega$ is the set of all subsets of $\Omega$, there is no way to produce a subset of $\Omega$ that is not in the sigma algebra.  That is, there are no non-measurable sets.  That is why "nothing can go wrong."